# npm install websocket error on Windows

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a chat server using Node . To do that I need to download Websocket plugin which requires me to run

C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install websocket
I have installed Python latest version too. I get following error when I run above command.

http://ScrnSht.com/bcqhhq

Does anyone know how to install the websocket ?

Comment: Like the error message says, you need to have Visual Studio installed to build the code.  Do you?

Comment: I have the Visual Studio Express 2010 Installed. C++,C#.

Comment: I get this error as well, with both installed. Perhaps Someone out there has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt, navigate to the root directory of your node installation using cd command, for me the root node folder is "c:\Program Files\nodejs"

```
cd "c:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

When here, type this `

```
npm install http-server -g
```

This will install http-server. "-g" means globally, this wont let the system throw errors relating to wrong directory or "package.json" file missing. The "-g" will take care of locating all of these.

After this type:

```
npm install websocket@1.0.3 -g
```

Again "-g" will take care for you. The websocket version mentioned here works fine. The other versions, I am not quite sure about.

You are good to go! Happy coding!

(The answer assumes that you have node and npm already installed.)